# Symfony Form Field Valid Even With Errors?

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have applied a form error to a form collection field (custom fieldset).

```
if ($this->isFieldset($form, $field) && !empty($error)) {
    $form->get($field)->addError(
        new FormError(
            ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)) . ' is invalid.')
        );
}
```

The form has an error applied to it but is still marked as valid?

[image]

As you see in the controller the form has the errors on the about_you child before isValid is called?

[image]

Any suggestions why?

Comment: Did you add your array before or after calling `$form->isValid()`?

Comment: Yes I add them when the form is first created (in an overridden form factor class which pull out the erros from Redis and adds them back to the form).

Comment: Have you tried writing a test for the custom fieldset or just created a form from that and then call getErrors()/isValid() in a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug through the code and found this snippet:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
   //...

    $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
        'errors' => $form->getErrors(),
        'valid' => $form->isSubmitted() ? $form->isValid() : true,  //<=== HERE
        'value' => $form->getViewData(),
        'data' => $form->getNormData(),
        'required' => $form->isRequired(),
        'size' => null,
        'label_attr' => $options['label_attr'],
        'compound' => $form->getConfig()->getCompound(),
        'method' => $form->getConfig()->getMethod(),
        'action' => $form->getConfig()->getAction(),
        'submitted' => $form->isSubmitted(),
    ));
}
```

This seems to be the *only* place where `valid` is set. Note that it happens during buildView! Everything afterwards will not effect the value of `valid`.

However, not everything is in vain as you can simply use `$form->isValid()` to check, if the form is *currently* valid, as we can see in the following snippet:

```
public function isValid()
{
    if (!$this->submitted) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->isDisabled()) {
        return true;
    }

    return 0 === count($this->getErrors(true));
}
```

Comment: So I could override buildView in my form and manually set it? I am doing something weird which is why I am getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading. The problem is definitely not in the FormView as can be seen on the attached image in question. The breakpoint is set before `createView()` is called and shows the Element\Form (not FormView) with the error. At that line a call to `isValid()` is made. When stepping to the next line the if block should be skipped. @Kal can you confirm this happens?

Comment: To be honest I don't know.. I just saw your updated question and it seems to me, that you actually *do* call `createView()` at the very end. Is your output from before that?

Comment: You actually got me on the righ trackt. I overridden the buildView method and checked the form field for errors so thanks :)